# absolute positioning a footer

Tags: html, css

I have a container containing one float left and one float right div.

I want to position a footer on the right side div on the floor. Both left and right divs need to expand relative to the tallest div and the footer should stay on the bottom of the right side div at all times.

How can I achieve this? Can someone please provide me an example or point me to tutorial?[image]

**EDIT:**

---

OK, sorry for my terrible pic but I think you get the idea. Also, if the left div grows taller than the right, the right div should grow with the left and vise versa. If the content on the right grows, it should not overflow onto the footer.

---

**EDIT**

This is a screenshot of the latest attempt by jackthetipper. The footer is not yet on the bottom of the right side div even though content has been added to the left.[image]

Comment: Its kind of hard to picture what you are trying to achieve. Do you have a photo or link to any working code?

Comment: 1. open ms paint. 2. draw what u are trying to achieve. 3. upload and let us point u in the direction of how to do it.

Comment: Hi Nick, no, I'm sorry but I don't have a pic. Maybe I can try to make one. Let me try, brb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fkZdU/). I believe this is what you are looking for:

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="left">Left</div>
    <div id="right">Right</div>
    <div id="rightfooter">Text</div>
</div>
​
```

CSS

```
#wrapper {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
}
#left{
    background-color: #82ff68;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
}
#right{
    background-color: #ff5c4a;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
}
#rightfooter {
    height: 1em;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: blue;
    float: right;
}​
```

**EDIT after comments**

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fkZdU/2/) with footer in the div

**EDIT 2 after comments**

Second [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TLePz/) with expanding heights (dependant on each other)

Comment: Almost there, I believe he wants the footer within the right div

Comment: @jacktheripper, it looks good but the only thing is that the footer needs to be contained within the right div and stay on the floor of that div.

Comment: @jacktheripper, OK, it looks really good but I've edited the css on the left div to `height: 150%;` and the right div does not grow to the same height. I'd like that to happen if possible.

Comment: @Muzz setting the height to 150% is not the way to test the code for your autogrow requirements. 150% doesn't make sense! Instead add more content to your divs and see them grow

Comment: @Muzz well, I was just trying it and it didn't seem to work. Not the testing, but the code didn't autogrow. See if my sample is any use to you else we'll just have to wait for Jack to come back with a fixed code

Comment: @bPratik, OK, I've added some dummy text in the left div and there are two issues. One, the left div does not expand to the height of the content and the last thing I noticed is that the right div will not expand to the height of the left div.

Comment: @bPratik. I've tried it but neither the left or right div will grow with the content. The content just overflows outside of the divs.

Comment: @jacktheripper, I've tried it but it still isn't right. I've taken a screenshot that I'll post above. You'll see that the footer isn't on the floor of the right div.

Comment: @jacktheripper, I still see the same issue. Say that we have a lot of content in the left div, mor so than the in the right. The footer does not stay on the floor of the right div but instead, stays below the content on the right. The footer needs to stay on the floor of the tallest div. If the tallest div is the left, then the footer should follow that. If the content is taller on the right, the footer should follow that. Whichever div is tallest, the footer should be on the bottom.

Comment: @jacktheripper, I was able to get this working by adding 100% height to `#content1` and `#content2` divs. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Follow http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/developing_with_web_standards/csslayout/2-col/ for a good understanding of the layout you are after.

Now to achieve the footer in right `div`, change the `HTML` in of the finished layout http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/developing_with_web_standards/csslayout/2-col/finished.html to something like:

```
<div id="sidebar">
<div>
    <h2>Column 2</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Mauris vel magna.</p>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="/">Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="/">Link 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="/">Link 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="/">Link 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="/">Link 6</a></li>
        <li><a href="/">Link 7</a></li>
        <li><a href="/">Link 8</a></li>
        <li><a href="/">Link 9</a></li>
        <li><a href="/">Link 10</a></li>
        <li><a href="/">Link 11</a></li>
        <li><a href="/">Link 12</a></li>
        <li><a href="/">Link 13</a></li>
        <li><a href="/">Link 14</a></li>
        <li><a href="/">Link 15</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="sub-footer">
    <p>Footer</p>
</div>
</div>
```

And then add the following `CSS`:

```
# {
    padding: 5px 10px;
    background: #CC9;
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 205px;
}
```